# how to get modifiedby property of a file for showing file details sharepoint C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, office-dev-pnp

I want to display files from a sharepoint folder that were modified by username. please help me for this. Also tell me how to show this file with sorting order by datetime.

I tried using
docName.Add(file.ModifiedBy);
property but its not available, here is the code:

```
public List<string> getFiles(ClientContext CContext,string INVOICENO)
        {
            List list = CContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");


            CContext.Load(list);
            CContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            CContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            CContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();
            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
            List<string> docName = new List<string>();
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                if(INVOICENO==null)
                {
                    INVOICENO = "";
                }
                string foldername = INVOICENO.ToString();
                if (f.Name == foldername)
                {
                    CContext.Load(f.Files);
                    CContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                    foreach (File file in fileCol)
                    {
                        docName.Add(file.Name);
                        docName.Add(file.TimeLastModified.ToShortDateString());
                       

                    }
                }
            }
            return docName.ToList();

        }
```

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? Do you want to modify `docName` to have strings with values like: `John @ 10-03-2020, 23:59:59 UTC`?

Comment: have strings with values like: John @ 10-03-2020 also modifiedBy:username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my testing and research, you can use **CAML Query** to display the files modified by the username from the SharePoint folder.

Here is an example you can refer to:(sorted by modification time in ascending order)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientContext = GetonlineContext();
        Web site = clientContext.Web;

        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Library Name");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor' /><Value Type='User'>UserName</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields /><QueryOptions /></View>";
        
        ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(query);

        clientContext.Load(collListItem);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in collListItem)
        {
            
            Debug.WriteLine("Name:"+item["FileLeafRef"]+"\n"+"Modified"+item["Modified"]);
        }
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    }
```

[image]